Vdb-export to blender not showing
using embergen 1.2.1, blender 4.0.2
i’m exporting a solid looking and working simulation in an vdb-format.

when importing into blender, nothing shows in the viewport.

the only way i got to see something, is, by choosing “flames” under the “grids” inside of the volume settings (right-hand-side, green cloud).

this only works in the viewport shading mode “solid” and isn’t visible in the render preview or final render.

also it’s weird because a vdb-file exported out of embergen beta 0.7.5.2 works completely fine in the viewport same as the final render.

any tips and tricks that might help are welcome. thanks in advance!

You have to give the object a material which uses the smoke and fire information. I would recommend watching a tutorial on fire simulation in Blender for that. You do not need to create the simulation, but a similar material like for a simulation.

thanks for your response. the issue seems to be the density 'grid' / 'attribute' which apparently is empty / doesn’t work. i made a shader only with the 'flames' information which seems to work now.
